# libgdx-html5 : texture dispose generate a bufferunderflowexception

Tags: html, textures, libgdx, dispose, bufferunderflowexception

I'm developping games with LIBGDX on ANDROID. Today, i've tried to generate one of my project in a HTML5 version. I put the content of the WAR folder on my server. All is fine except 2 things. I'll present you here just one of these 2 issues.

The problem : when a texture has to be disposed (by the call of its method dispose()), i get a BufferUnderflowException. It happens everytime.

Here is the sample code which is automatically generated when you create a new project :

```
public class TexDispose implements ApplicationListener
{
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture texture;

    @Override
    public void create() {      
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        texture.dispose(); // HERE IS THE ERROR
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }
}
```

Has one of you already met this issue..? If yes, how can i avoid that (except by not disposing anything lol) ?

Thank you ! ;)

Comment: Can you include a backtrace from the exception?